# Error only if not in main method: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have two methods that are exactly the same, the only difference is that one of them is called while the app is running, and the other is a `main(String[] args)` method.

The main method works, although that only posts console information.

The other method, however, is supposed to return the connection object. Instead, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

**Working code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();

        throw e;
    }

    System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "randy",
            "test");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;

    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("Happy");
    } else {
        throw new SQLException("Failed to setup the connection");
    }
}
```

**result:**

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Happy
```

---

However if I call it as a regular method instead of in my `main` method, I get the error. This is the code:

**Error code:**

```
public static Connection connect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    if(connection != null){
        return connection;
    }

    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

    System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "randy",
            "test");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;

    }

    if (connection != null) {
        return connection;
    } else {
        throw new SQLException("Failed to setup the connection");
    }
}
```

**result:**

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

---

Why do I get that error and how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Where is this regular method? in same class? it seem you have classpath issue.

Comment: if the regular method `connect()` is called from within say a Java EE web application, make sure your oracle driver jars are in the web-inf/lib directory.

Comment: @AkioHamasaki Yes it is a web app, I will try that solution tomorrow, I had the jar added the regular way. Make it an answer if you want.

Comment: @Randy i added it as an answer. let us know how it goes when you get a chance.

Comment: It's not related to your issue but please note that `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` is out dated for a long time, you are supposed to use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the regular method `connect()` is called from within say a Java EE web application, make sure your oracle driver jars are in the web-inf/lib directory